# Why running sed command cutting my path first letter?

Tags: bash, sed

```
sed -i s/CUSTOMER_UNIT=".*"/CUSTOMER_UNIT="Test" core/src/main/java/com/appname/core/AppConstants.kt
```

I am running this sed command as a result I get this

```
sed: ore/src/main/java/com/appname/core/AppConstants.kt: No such file or directory
```

It remove the first letter of core -> ore

but if I just run command find `ore/src/main/java/com/appname/core/AppConstants.kt it this file exists`

Comment: Do you run this command on MacOS?

Comment: `s/CUSTOMER_UNIT=".*"/CUSTOMER_UNIT="Test"` should be quoted.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are trying to have the results = core or ore
but when i replicate I am able to get core. One thing I noticed is in your example you are missing the terminating / for your sed command after "Test"

```
sed -i s/CUSTOMER_UNIT=".*"/CUSTOMER_UNIT="Test"/ core/src/main/java/com/appname/core/AppConstants.kt
sed: can't read core/src/main/java/com/appname/core/AppConstants.kt: No such file or directory
```

if you are trying to cut the C from core and you can manually validate the path exists I would be sure that you have proper permissions

Answer (score 0):

The command should be enclosed in quotes and be ended with "/".

```
sed -i 's/CUSTOMER_UNIT=".*"/CUSTOMER_UNIT="Test"/' core/src/main/java/com/appname/core/AppConstants.kt
```